# Why is JSON.parse not outputing the correct result?

Tags: json

Here's my code:

```
var jsonStr = (JSON.stringify(data, ['flightPositions', 'flightId', 'positions', 'lat', 'lon', 'date'], 4));
alert(jsonStr);

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
alert(jsonObj.flightPositions);        
},
```

The output from JSON.stringify seems to be correct. I've run it through JSLint and gives me no error:

```
{
"flightPositions": [
    {
        "flightId": 621650693,
        "positions": [
            {
                "lat": 40.4272,
                "lon": -74.3395,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:31:55.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.6833,
                "lon": -74.1667,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:32:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.6133,
                "lon": -74.0122,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:32:55.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.7538,
                "lon": -74.0989,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:33:55.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.8125,
                "lon": -74.1044,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:34:55.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.8147,
                "lon": -74.1832,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:35:55.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.7624,
                "lon": -74.2316,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:36:55.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.6829,
                "lon": -74.2523,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:37:55.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "flightId": 621650363,
        "positions": [
            {
                "lat": 40.7859,
                "lon": -74.0978,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:29:21.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.7738,
                "lon": -74.143,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:30:21.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.7169,
                "lon": -74.1948,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:31:21.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.6602,
                "lon": -74.2524,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:32:21.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.5888,
                "lon": -74.3109,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:33:21.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.5004,
                "lon": -74.3464,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:34:21.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.4213,
                "lon": -74.3074,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:35:21.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.3152,
                "lon": -74.2497,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:36:21.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.2224,
                "lon": -74.1577,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:37:21.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.163,
                "lon": -74.0203,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:38:21.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "flightId": 621650734,
        "positions": [
            {
                "lat": 40.6742,
                "lon": -74.1728,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:29:15.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.6369,
                "lon": -74.1976,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:30:15.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.7258,
                "lon": -74.1342,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:30:22.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.8227,
                "lon": -74.0561,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:32:15.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.7436,
                "lon": -74.2853,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:33:15.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.6199,
                "lon": -74.2754,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:34:15.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.5328,
                "lon": -74.2924,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:35:15.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.4304,
                "lon": -74.2721,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:36:15.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.3341,
                "lon": -74.2384,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:37:15.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.2547,
                "lon": -74.173,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:38:15.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "flightId": 621633505,
        "positions": [
            {
                "lat": 40.3481,
                "lon": -74.7084,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:29:35.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.3788,
                "lon": -74.6202,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:30:35.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.4126,
                "lon": -74.5206,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:31:35.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.4436,
                "lon": -74.4448,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:32:35.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.45,
                "lon": -74.4333,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:32:35.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.481,
                "lon": -74.3348,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:33:47.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.5225,
                "lon": -74.2702,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:34:47.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.5691,
                "lon": -74.2228,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:35:47.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.6234,
                "lon": -74.1737,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:36:47.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.6804,
                "lon": -74.1765,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:37:47.000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "flightId": 621650749,
        "positions": [
            {
                "lat": 40.6906,
                "lon": -74.2433,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:34:54.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.631,
                "lon": -74.5142,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:35:54.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 39.6624,
                "lon": -74.6148,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:36:54.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.6833,
                "lon": -74.1667,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:37:00.000Z"
            },
            {
                "lat": 40.7207,
                "lon": -74.1416,
                "date": "2015-10-31T13:37:54.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

[alert output from JSON.stringify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpLZf.png)

However, I am getting the following for the JSON.parse:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

What could be wrong here?

---

**UPDATE**

Changed alert to console.log (without concatenating string) and it gives me the following output:

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]
```

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IFyX.png)

Comment: use `console.log` instead of `alert` for debugging JS, `alert` automatically converts array items to strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to `stringify` and `parse` JSON is correct, the behavior you are seeing is due to the `alert` function. `alert` automatically tries to convert the parameter to a human-readable string (not a JSON string), in your case it converts every item inside the `flightPositions` array to string.

To debug JS you should use the `console.log` method ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)) and the browser developer's tools (use F12 to open the tools).

```
var jsonStr = (JSON.stringify(data, ['flightPositions', 'flightId', 'positions', 'lat', 'lon', 'date'], 4));
console.log(jsonStr);

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
console.log(jsonObj.flightPositions);
```

Comment: Thank you. Did that, but still gives me the same output (uploaded a new image above from the Firefox console)

Comment: How did you print the output to the console? You have to print the object like in my example, without concatenating string (eg: `console.log('These are the nearby flights:' + jsonObj.flightPositions)` will not work, it will convert again everything to string).

Comment: Changed accordingly, without concatenating string. Gives me this: Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]

Comment: Try with chrome, it will allow you to expand the objects inside. For Firefox try with `console.dir` instead of `console.log`